# Using Excel to GROUP BY and find date WHERE MAX

Tags: excel, date, max

My problem is I have a table of data structured as below :

```
+---------------+------------+---------+
| recipe number |    date    | quality |
+---------------+------------+---------+
|           154 | 01/01/2020 |       2 |
|           154 | 01/03/2020 |       3 |
|           154 | 01/05/2020 |       1 |
|           154 | 01/07/2020 |       2 |
|           222 | 01/01/2020 |       3 |
|           222 | 01/03/2020 |       2 |
|           222 | 01/05/2020 |       2 |
|           222 | 01/07/2020 |       1 |
|           888 | 01/01/2020 |       1 |
|           888 | 01/03/2020 |       3 |
|           888 | 01/05/2020 |       2 |
|           888 | 01/07/2020 |       3 |
|           666 | 01/01/2020 |       2 |
|           666 | 01/03/2020 |       3 |
|           666 | 01/05/2020 |       3 |
|           666 | 01/07/2020 |       3 |
|           777 | 01/01/2020 |       1 |
|           777 | 01/03/2020 |       2 |
|           777 | 01/05/2020 |       3 |
|           777 | 01/07/2020 |       1 |
|           123 | 01/09/2020 |       3 |
|           254 | 01/01/2020 |       2 |
|           254 | 01/03/2020 |       3 |
|           745 | 01/01/2020 |       1 |
|           745 | 01/03/2020 |       3 |
|           745 | 01/05/2020 |       2 |
|           745 | 01/07/2020 |       3 |
|           578 | 01/11/2020 |       3 |
|           578 | 01/01/2021 |       3 |
|           578 | 01/03/2021 |       1 |
|           578 | 01/05/2021 |       3 |
|           678 | 01/07/2021 |       2 |
|           999 | 01/09/2021 |       1 |
|           999 | 01/11/2021 |       1 |
+---------------+------------+---------+
```

The final answer I want is that I need a table of each recipe number and a simple yes/no whether that recipe decreased in quality over time, at all.

There are some recipes which only have one entry, and others which only increased in quality - these need to be answered "no"

EG:

| recipe | decreased? |
| --- | --- |
| 154 | yes |
| 666 | no |

Unfortunately, I'm limited to only Excel for this, though I understand doing it in other environments is probably easier.

I have tried a max(index+match) to see if I can return the highest quality for each recipe (and the lowest with a min). But I got stuck at trying to get Excel to return an array of qualities conditional on which recipe to look at.

I also tried PowerQuery but the problem seems too complex for that utility.

I've done some more thinking and some psuedocode that would solve it is:

```
For each recipe number:
  1) Find me the max quality and the date where it happened
  2) Find me any quality lower than this number where the date it happened is 
     after step 1
  3) If the date of step 1 is earlier (less than) the date of step 2, output 
     "yes", otherwise "no"
```

Translating that into Excel 2016 is a bit difficult

Comment: What, exactly, does `over time` mean?  Beginning vs end? End time quality lower than max time quality?  Any decrease with min time quality occurring after max time quality? For `154`, it starts at `2` and ends at `2` and in the middle goes both up and down.  What version of Excel?  With Office 365, you can probably do this with formulas. If not, it would be rather simple with Power Query.

Comment: well each recipe is evaluated at different dates, if a recipe is of 2 quality at one date then 3 on a date subsequent it would be a "yes". I also thought powerquery might handle it but i'm inexperienced with powerquery and i'm struggling to get anywhere more complex than find the maximum quality of each recipe - particularly i can't find the date of the max for each recipe

Comment: Then I don't understand 666. It is 2 on 01/01 and 3 on a subsequent date but you show it as No. 154 is 2 on 01/01 and 3 on 01/03 and you show it as Yes. You need more consistent rules.

Comment: Sorry, as in the original question, 666 is a "no" because it went from 2 to 3 and never back down. I'm still working on the problem and confusing myself trying to think through this pretend data compared to my original problem. the problem is looking for recipes that DECREASE in quality. Ignore my dumb mistake in my comment.

Comment: Is 1 the highest or lowest quality? And what version of Excel?

Comment: 1 is the lowest in this toy data, 3 is the highest. my excel version is 2016

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233212/discussion-between-k-bort-and-ron-rosenfeld).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Edit:*** *Thanks to @TomSharpe who pointed out some logic errors => incorrect results, I have had to modify the M-code and also remove the formula method.  I believe the code below satisfies your requirements*

This can be done in Power Query

1. Group by Recipe
2. Determine the first date of the highest quality
3. See if any dates after the first date have a lower quality
4. If so then "yes" else "no"

Examine the comments and step through the Applied Steps window to better understand the algorithm.

**M Code**

```
let

//read in the data
//change table name in next line to actual table name
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table18"]}[Content],

//set data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"recipe number", Int64.Type}, {"date", type date}, {"quality", Int64.Type}}),

//group by recipe number
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"recipe number"}, {

//(t) is each subtable returned
        {"Quality Decrease", (t)=>
            let 

            //List.Max(quality) => highest quality rating
            //Filter the subtable to only show qualities of that value
            //then, with List.Min(....[date]) return the earliest date

               firstBest= List.Min(Table.SelectRows(t, each [quality] = List.Max(t[quality]))[date]),

            //Filter the subtable to only show dates > firstBest date and with quality worse than the highest quality rating

               decrQual = Table.SelectRows(t, each [date] > firstBest and [quality] < List.Max(t[quality]))
            in 

            //check if resultant table is empty
               if Table.IsEmpty(decrQual) then "no" else "yes", Text.Type 
               }
         })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

Comment: Very good, I need to get better at understanding M code. It's interesting that in recipe 999 it comes up with a decrease although both qualities are the same - I can see that's a special case where the min and max are the same so it compares the dates and first date of best qual (1) is < last date of worst qual (also 1).

Comment: @TomSharpe  Thanks for noticing that.  It is a fairly simple fix and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much Ron, this makes a lot of sense.